# Java polymorphic method cannot be resolved

Tags: java, compiler-errors, polymorphism, abstract-class, subclass

I am a programming newbie, so please bear with me.  I searched and could not find an existing thread that could answer this question.  I wrote the following code which was supposed to spit out either stock.toString() or bond.toString() canned phrases based on whether the security object was identified as a stock or a bond by the user.  However, I am getting "security cannot be resolved" compiler errors.  I imagine this is an issue because the class of the security object is not defined at compile time.  Is that true?  If so, is there any way around that without resorting to reflection methods?  Thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double thePrice;
    double theShares;
    double theEarnings;
    double theRate;
    String securityType;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Is it a stock or a bond?");
    securityType = in.nextLine();

    if (securityType.compareToIgnoreCase("stock") == 0) {
        System.out.println("Successfully set to STOCK");
        System.out.println("What are the earnings?");
        theEarnings = in.nextDouble();
        Stock security = new Stock();
        security.setEarnings(theEarnings);
    }

    else if (securityType.compareToIgnoreCase("bond") == 0) {
        System.out.println("Successfully set to BOND");
        System.out.println("What is the rate?");
        theRate = in.nextDouble();
        Bond security = new Bond();
        security.setRate(theRate);
    }

    System.out.println("What is the price");
    thePrice = in.nextDouble();     

    System.out.println("How many shares are there?");
    theShares = in.nextDouble();

    security.setPrice(thePrice);
    security.setShares(theShares);

    System.out.println(security);
}
```

Thanks to @Jigur Joshi, @penartur, and the rest.  Here is the solution we came up with, but let me know if there is a better alternative.  And I am adding an else statement to clean up in case the securityType is neither "stock" nor "bond" :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

                ...
    Security security = null;
    String securityType;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Is it a stock or a bond?");
    securityType = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is the price"); 
    thePrice = in.nextDouble();      

    System.out.println("How many shares are there?"); 
    theShares = in.nextDouble(); 

    if (securityType.compareToIgnoreCase("stock") == 0) {
        System.out.println("Successfully registered STOCK");
        security = new Stock();
        System.out.println("What are the earnings?"); 
        theEarnings = in.nextDouble(); 
        ((Stock) security).setEarnings(theEarnings); 
    }

    if (securityType.compareToIgnoreCase("bond") == 0) {
        System.out.println("Successfully registered BOND");
        security = new Bond();
        System.out.println("What is the rate?"); 
        theRate = in.nextDouble(); 
        ((Bond) security).setRate(theRate);
    }

    security.setPrice(thePrice); 
    security.setShares(theShares); 

        System.out.println(security); 

}
```

Comment: how are ur objects `Bond` and `Stock` related? is `Bond` extending `Stock`?

Comment: Bond and Stock are subclasses of an abstract class called Security

Answer (score 6):

Declare it out side of if else so that it would be available after if else

Assuming `Stock` is super class of `Bond`, if not declare `security` like

```
 Object security = null;
```

Make it

```
 Stock security = null;
 if (securityType.compareToIgnoreCase("stock") == 0) {
        System.out.println("Successfully set to STOCK");
        System.out.println("What are the earnings?");
        theEarnings = in.nextDouble();
        security = new Stock();
        security.setEarnings(theEarnings);
    }

    else if (securityType.compareToIgnoreCase("bond") == 0) {
        System.out.println("Successfully set to BOND");
        System.out.println("What is the rate?");
        theRate = in.nextDouble();
        security = new Bond();
        security.setRate(theRate);
    }
```

---

**See**

- [§ 14.4.2 Scope of Local Variable Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#263461)

Comment: Then a NullReferenceException would be possible.

Comment: OP needs to formulate what they want to do in the first place. The code doesn't seem to be good anyway. PS: Whoops, just have noticed that the question is on Java. At the first look I thought it is C# :)

Comment: Oh, and your code will fail if `Bond` is not an ancestor of `Stock` (which is quite likely).

Comment: In this case, compiler says setEarnings(Double) is undefined for the type Object (or Security if I initialize with `code`Security security = null`code` - which is true.  That method is only defined in the Stock class.

Comment: Cast it to Stock while calling method

Comment: Thank you @Jigar Joshi and @penartur!  I set Security security = null outside the if/else block, and casted to Stock/Bond in the appropriate method calls, and now it seems to be working.  I know I need to clean up the else block now.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not with the types.

You have `security` defined in the inner scope, and it simply doesn't exists outside (where you do the `security.setPrice`. What's even worse, the code could not be easily fixed, as `security` won't be defined at all (be it inner scope or not) when the `securityType` is neither "bond" nor "stock".

However I guess that what you wanted to do is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double thePrice;
    double theShares;
    double theEarnings;
    double theRate;
    String securityType;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Is it a stock or a bond?");
    securityType = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is the price");
    thePrice = in.nextDouble();     

    System.out.println("How many shares are there?");
    theShares = in.nextDouble();

    if (securityType.compareToIgnoreCase("stock") == 0) {
        System.out.println("Successfully set to STOCK");
        System.out.println("What are the earnings?");
        theEarnings = in.nextDouble();
        Stock security = new Stock();
        security.setEarnings(theEarnings);
        security.setPrice(thePrice);
        security.setShares(theShares);
        System.out.println(security);
    }

    else if (securityType.compareToIgnoreCase("bond") == 0) {
        System.out.println("Successfully set to BOND");
        System.out.println("What is the rate?");
        theRate = in.nextDouble();
        Bond security = new Bond();
        security.setRate(theRate);
        security.setPrice(thePrice);
        security.setShares(theShares);
        System.out.println(security);
    }

}
```

Of course this is a terrible solution, but you have to clarify yourself on the task first.

Comment: Thank you penartur.  I am trying to learn from this.  Bond and Stock are subclasses of the abstract class Security, and I want the program to run the appropriate version of toString() (implicit in the System.out.println(security) call) based on the class of the security (Stock or Bond) at run-time without having to rewrite that call statement and the setPrice and setShares calls (both those methods are inherited from Security).  I have a feeling that will be useful in the future.

Comment: @MattM What if `securityType` is neither bond nor stock?

Comment: Yes, I realize I need to put in an else statement to mop up in that case, but I'm more concerned about understanding the compile-time error right now.

Comment: The compile-time error is caused by the scope problems; but this is not the only problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the scope of your variables. `security` is defined only inside the if/else blocks.

You can change the code to something like this:

```
Object security; //you can use common superclass of Bond and Stock (maybe Security?)

if (securityType.compareToIgnoreCase("stock") == 0) {
    /* ... */
    Stock stock = new Stock();
    stock.setEarnings(theEarnings);
    security = stock;
}

else if (securityType.compareToIgnoreCase("bond") == 0) {
    /* ... */
    Bond bond = new Bond();
    bond.setRate(theRate);
    security = bond;
}

/* ... */
System.out.println(security);
```